# How to split a string when a few certain characters occur

Tags: javascript, split

I am trying to write a function that takes a string as input and returns an array of strings. Input string is a code that consists of small parts put in tandem. Each part consists of a mix of numbers and letters that is separated by a white space and they only end in certain ways.

each part is like this:

`74a 2b 23d 1P QQ`

it only ends in these ways:

`QQ`  `Q` or another mix with `X` in it like `3X` or `12X`. So when I see these three parts I understand that it is the end of that part, so I should split after it.

`split(74a 2b 23d 1P QQ 45b 1111a Q 3X 11a 5c 5X QQ 11a 65e 45b 36X 44a 88a 3a 245b 656c QQ)`

should give this output:

```
[74a 2b 23d 1P QQ, 45b 1111a Q, 3X, 11a 5c 5X, QQ, 11a 65e 45b 36X, 44a 88a 3a 245b 656c QQ]
```

Comment: you have to try regex

Comment: Please share your attempt. Also, your split call and expected output is invalid code--if it's a string, indicate that with quotes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pattern `/\s*(.*?(\bQQ?|X))/g` and access the capture group to get your match without leading spaces. This uses a non-greedy wildcard `.*?` followed by an alternation matching either of your ending options.

```js
const s = "74a 2b 23d 1P QQ 45b 1111a Q 3X 11a 5c 5X QQ 11a 65e 45b 36X 44a 88a 3a 245b 656c QQ";

const pattern = /\s*(.*?(\bQQ?|X))/g;
const result = [...s.matchAll(pattern)].map(e => e[1]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: After researching regex a bit, I think I understand your answer. But what should I do if the given code includes an unfinished part at the end. How can I catch that? I can either raise an error that says "incorrect input" or get that unfinished one in the array as well, and then check each element of the array to see if they are finished parts. Right now it doesn't get the last part if it is unfinished, so I can't raise an error by checking each item of the array.

Comment: You can add the end-of-line anchor `$` like  `/\s*(.*?(\bQQ?|X|.$))/g`. This will give you the last chunk even if it doesn't end with one of the other delimiters. Or just pre-validate with `/(\bQQ?|X)$/` before matching.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it adds the last one now. But it also adds an empty string as well.

Comment: `.$` should prevent an empty string. Maybe `\S$`? Please post the string you're matching against that includes the empty string.